Smart Panel not autopopulating
I have a custom button on the Sales Orders screen , when the button is clicked, a smart panel is displayed. I want the smart panel to auto-populate but the code I have only populates the first 2 fields. What could be the issue with my code and how can I fix it?
Code that displays the smart panel:
  public PXFilter<SOQuickPayment> POSQuickPayment;
        private void ShowQuickPaymentPanel(SOOrder order, string PaymentType)
        {
            
            POSQuickPayment.Current.CuryOrigDocAmt = order.CuryOrderTotal;
            POSQuickPayment.Current.CuryID = order.CuryID;
            POSQuickPayment.Current.DocDesc = "Text";

            if (PaymentType == "Card")
            {
                POSQuickPayment.Current.PaymentMethodID = POSPreferences.SelectSingle().PaymentMethodsCard;
                POSQuickPayment.Current.CashAccountID = POSPreferences.SelectSingle().CardAccount;
            }

            else if (PaymentType == "Cash")
            {
                POSQuickPayment.Current.PaymentMethodID = POSPreferences.SelectSingle().PaymentMethodsCash;
                POSQuickPayment.Current.CashAccountID = POSPreferences.SelectSingle().CashAccount;
            }


         
            POSQuickPayment.Current.ExtRefNbr = PaymentType + " Payment";
          

          

            // Display the QuickPayment smart panel
            POSQuickPayment.AskExt();
            


        }



You may have to call POSQuickPayment.Update(POSQuickPayment.Current) or use SetValueExt instead of using the properties directly.
